# Can I use Selenium for load testing AJAX based asp.net website?

Tags: asp.net, selenium, load-testing

I am asked to find a load testing tool, which will load test an AJAX based asp.net web application.
Please let me know whether Selenium is suited for this situation, or there are another tools to automate load testing?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend having a look at [Browsermob](http://browsermob.com) as a provider for Load testing with Selenium. They allow you to upload your test script, schedule the test and then have a look at all the results that are returned

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is not suited for that kind of task. It simulates the behavior of one user. I recommand instead Apache JMeter (http://jmeter.apache.org/).

Comment: Does JMeter handle "chatty" AJAX applications that are constantly speaking to the web server?

Comment: JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.